# How to add host printer (Ubuntu) to Virtualbox (Windows guest)

Tags: virtualbox, printing, virtualbox-networking

OK everyone:  I have a Windows XP Virtualbox machine, running inside of Ubuntu 16.04.  I have a network printer successfully working with the Ubuntu host that I'd like to connect to the Virtualbox machine, but I'm having a heck of a time doing it.

I REALLY want to add the printer using "Host Only" mode for the virtual machine, rather than "Bridged"...I don't want the virtual machine to have network access right now.  So, having researched things on Google,

- I made certain that the printer was "shared" in Ubuntu and the "print
  from internet" option was enabled.
- I found that you have to add a Host networking adapter in Virtualbox, which I set up and connected the virtual machine to

Even after this, however, I cannot get the Windows XP guest machine to "see" the printer when going through the "add printer" dialog (I used the "network printer" option, as several instructions advised me to do.

In desperation, I went ahead and tried to do it using "Bridged" mode...but that doesn't work either.  Another set of instructions advised that I should make certain the printer was added in CUPS...**edit**  Initially, I couldn't access CUPS, but I found the fix for that.  It looks like the printer is already available there, with the right settings checked (shared, available over the Internet)...but I still can't "see" it from Virtual Box.

I've honestly tried to research this, and I'm sure I'm leaving something out that I tried (I'll add it if I think of it again), but honestly, I'm about to throw my hands up!  What the heck am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT/UPDATE** Someone asked about the printer being connected to the Ubuntu/host machine via USB, so I thought I'd clarify:  it's a wireless/network printer.  However, my understanding is that if the printer can be reached via the host and is "shared" in linux, that shouldn't matter.

After some time, I was finally able to get printing working in the virtual machine...using **NAT** mode.  An unfortunate side effect of this, however, is that now the virtual machine has access to the Internet, and that's what I was trying to prevent by using **Host-Only** mode.  I'm still not understanding why Host-Only isn't working.  I'm going to try and determine the virtual machine's IP (I'm not sure, but I'm guessing it has a subnet address):  my plan is to see if I can firewall it somehow while preserving printer access...but it's not a perfect solution.

Comment: Is your printer connected to the Ubuntu host via USB? You could go to Devices -> USB and dedicate that USB port directly to Windows XP for the time when you need printing. Then you can release it and host will detect as if printer was connected to the computer again. For both machines it should be like you would move the cable from one to another.

Comment: "Nobody," thanks so much for responding.  It's actually a wireless printer, so I don't think that would work.  I have an update with more information above; that may or may not shed more light on the problem.  Thanks again!

Comment: Same problem here. Virtual box on windows. The ubuntu 20.04 cannot see any printers on the network.

Comment: I can't get access to the network printer using NAT mode from the guest Windows 10. I have the printer with Share set for its properties in the Ubuntu 20.04 host. I saw on the web advice to also set up a (second) Network Adapter (in VirtualBox) set to a Bridged Adapter but that didn't help.